# 20-bit msp430 (large memory model) breakpoints not being hit using mspdebug

Tags: debugging, msp430

I am working with an MSP430F5438A interfaced to an Olimex MSP430_JTAG-TINY-V2 using Spy-By-Wire. We are using the large memory model. Using `mspdebug` we can set breakpoints in low memory (< 64kB) and these work fine. If an attempt is made to set a breakpoint in high memory (>64kB), although it is listed correctly the address has been truncated to 16-bits. So, for example, if I set a breakpoint at `0x12345` the CPU will be halted if code at `0x2345` is fetched.

I have also tried using the TI Launchpad (G2) as a debugger and I get the same results.

Googling for this issue has thrown up nothing (although perhaps I'm not looking for the right thing?) can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Is it possible these is a problem with your board?  Are you using a demo board, or is it one you've tracked yourself?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the board, as all other debugging facilities work. It's not a demo board, though.

I did find others who have experienced this problem (https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/p/62039/223969) but apart from an opinionated discussion about the necessity of integration testing, there doesn't seem to be much in the follow up comments that I can apply to my case.